# printing the turns of a recursive maze solution in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, printing

So I've been working on the following problem:

> I buried my sapphire then started walking. I always walked in a
>   straight line  following a compass direction (N, S, E, W). When I
>   stopped, I made a 90 degree  turn and continued walking. I might have
>   crossed my path, but I don’t remember.  Below are the number of meters
>   I travelled in each direction. I’m now lost and  must abandon this
>   record while I search for a way out. I’m placing this note under a
>   rock  at my final location. Perhaps some lucky adventurer will decode
>   my note and retrace my  steps to earn the treasure.    Unfortunately,
>   there is no record of where in the ruins the note was found. Instead,
>   you must write a program to  find the treasure.    Input  The first
>   line contains two integers X Y, representing the number of rows and
>   columns in the ruins. Maximum of  20 rows and 50 columns. The next X
>   lines show a grid map of the space. A period “.” is an empty square. A
>   hash “#” is a large boulder, marking a square that cannot be entered.
>   The next line has an integer N, the count of  the straight paths
>   walked. Maximum of 20 paths. The last line contains N integers
>   separated by spaces, showing  the successive path-lengths..    5 10
>
> ####
>
> ## ........#
>
> ## .#...##.#
>
> ## ...#....#
>
> ####  8  2 4 2 2 2 5 2 1    Output  Your program must print the same map, with the location of both the Sapphire (S) and the final
>
> location of the  message (F) marked. Also, label every turning point
>   with successive lowercase letters (if the same point is used  more
>   than once, print the letter for the later turn.) There is only one
>   route which follows the path-lengths in the  list.
>
> ####
>
> ## b.e.a..f#
>
> ## .#...##.#
>
> ## c.d#S.Fg#
>
> #

and I have made a recursive method that checks every direction starting from every open position of the maze until it finds the solution, however the output of the problem needs to be the mazes with the turns.

The problem is, when I use a recursive solution and edit the actual char[][] map, it never knows which path will lead to the actual finish, so it will create output like this:

d...d

.....

cbabc

d...d

but instead I would like it to show only one path, like this:

....d

.....

..abc

.....

Here is my incomplete solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SapphireSearch {

    private static int rs; // Row Size
    private static int cs; // Column Size

    private static int sr; // Save row (saves solution row)
    private static int sc; // Save col (saves solution col)
    private static Direction sd; // Save direction (saves solution dir)

    private static char[][] map; // the maze to traverse

    private static int n; // number of turns

    private static int[] go; // length of the turns

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getInput();
        for (int r = 0; r < rs; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < cs; c++)
                for (Direction d : Direction.values())
                    solve(sr = r, sc = c, sd = d, 0, false);
    }

    public static void solve(int r, int c, Direction d, int start,
            boolean printing) {
        if (isSolid(r, c))
            return;
        if (printing) {
            if (start == 0)
                map[r][c] = 'S';
            else
                map[r][c] = (char) (start - 1 + 'a');
            if (start == n) {
                map[r][c] = 'F';
                return;
            }
        }
        if (start == n - 1 && !printing) {
            solve(sr, sc, sd, 0, true);
            printArray(map);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int count = 0;
        while (start < go.length && count < go[start]) {
            count++;
            r += d.dr;
            c += d.dc;
            if (isSolid(r, c))
                return;
        }
        for (Direction t : d.turn())
            solve(r, c, t, start + 1, printing);
    }

    public static boolean isSolid(int r, int c) {
        return map[r][c] == '#';
    }

    public static void printArray(char[][] o) {
        for (int r = 0; r < o.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < o[r].length; c++)
                System.out.print(o[r][c]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void getInput() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        rs = s.nextInt();
        cs = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine(); // clear buffer
        map = new char[rs][cs];
        for (int r = 0; r < rs; r++) {
            int c = 0;
            char[] f = s.nextLine().trim().toCharArray();
            for (char t : f)
                map[r][c++] = t;
        }
        n = s.nextInt();
        go = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            go[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
}

enum Direction {
    // deltaR, deltaC
    up(-1, 0), down(1, 0), left(0, -1), right(0, 1);

    public int dr;
    public int dc;

    private Direction(int dr, int dc) {
        this.dr = dr;
        this.dc = dc;
    }

    public Direction[] turn() {
        Direction[] out = new Direction[2];
        switch (this) {
        case up:
        case down:
            out[0] = left;
            out[1] = right;
            break;
        case left:
        case right:
            out[0] = up;
            out[1] = down;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

**The question is:  building upon my recursive solve algorithm, what would be the best way to print the solution path (where it doesn't print out every path it tries to take)?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to build up your list of turns as you do the recursive search (I'm just listing the direction here for simplicity but you could store an object with co-ordinates as well for example).

If the path is (N,E,N,W,S) and then save that as you exit.

To do that keep the partial list so far and each recursive call COPY the list so far and add to it.

i.e.:

n

ne
nw Fail

nen
nes Fail

nenw

etc.

At the end you can either return the completed solution or if you need to handle multiple solutions have a final results list of lists that you insert the completed one into.

The key step is to copy the list so far so that recursion branches cannot interfere with each other.

Comment: wouldn't that significantly increase running time?  Cloning the solution array thousands of times

Comment: It will increase it, not to the point it becomes unperformant though. There are other options like using one solution array and then keep a pointer for what position you are at in the array. That's considerably more complex to manage and easier to get wrong though.